# What does the --force flag change about the behaviour of logrotate?

Tags: logrotate, log-rotation

I am trying to find out why logrotate is only rotating a subset of logfiles in a folder when run without the `--force` flag. The man page for `logrotate --force` simply says:

> Tells logrotate to force the rotation, even if it doesn't think this
>   is necessary. Sometimes this is useful after adding new entries to a
>   logrotate config file, or if old log files have been removed by hand,
>   as the new files will be created, and logging will continue correctly.

My current theory is that this is related to file age, as the unrotated files are written by a different application that resets log file ctime on each write.

The `/etc/logrotate.d/` configuration file is as follows:

```
"/var/log/web_app/*.log" {
  su www-data www-data
  daily
  rotate 21
  maxsize 2G
  compress
  dateext
  copytruncate
  delaycompress
  missingok
}
```

The `logrotate.status` file shows (note only `cgi.log` has actually been rotated):

```
"/var/log/web_app/cgi.log" 2019-2-11-6:25:34
"/var/log/web_app/api.log" 2019-2-11-6:0:0
"/var/log/web_app/db.log" 2019-2-11-6:0:0
```

And `logrotate --debug` reports:

```
rotating pattern: "/var/log/web_app/*.log"  after 1 days (21 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, log files >= 2147483648 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
switching euid to 33 and egid to 33
considering log /var/log/web_app/api.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/web_app/db.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/web_app/cgi.log
  log does not need rotating
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

`head /var/log/web_app/api.log` shows that this log file has not been rotated (3 days old at time of writing):

```
2019-02-08 16:50:54,492 - general (Process1-MainThread) - INFO - Starting instance of WEB_APP
```

`stat` on the same file shows:

```
  File: '/var/log/web_app/api.log'
  Size: 6307        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca11h/51729d    Inode: 751580      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (   33/www-data)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2019-02-11 13:17:46.639667970 +0000
Modify: 2019-02-11 09:16:43.779964966 +0000
Change: 2019-02-11 09:16:43.779964966 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever *logrotate* is determining whether a given file needs to be rotated, the `--force` flag makes it answer unconditionally *"yes, this file is in need of rotating"*. It simply makes `logrotate` disregard the configured rotation triggers - note that *age* is not the only possible trigger, it works the same way for *size*.

**If you know your rotation works with `--force`, but not without it, you likely want to proceed with `--debug` and without `--force`. You will get a line of explanation for every processed file.** If you used `--force` you would not see the explanations, as they would be skipped (see `findNeedRotating` in [`logrotate.c`](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/master/logrotate.c))

The `--force` flag will **not** make *logrotate* do anything that it would not have been doing anyway if the log file had aged/filled up to trigger the configured rotate condition. You are only enforcing it to happen right now - *potentially deleting the oldest file, so you usually want to avoid running it repeatedly*.